# How can I control exactly what fields of my Facebook profile are private?

Tags: privacy, facebook

All I can see under privacy settings are broad controls to let friends or friends or friends see your account details.

What I want to do for example is make my interests public but keep my favourite music private - something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your favorites

`http://www.facebook.com/USERNAME/favorites`

Select edit in the upper right and you should be presented with a layout similar to the following.

[image: Favorite]

Set the music section to `Only Me`